# SQL Condition statement

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I'm working with MySQL 5.6.23. In my database, I have two tables, tblFiles and tblLogs. The table tblFiles contains an ID (PK), the path of the file and the name of file (both VARCHAR).

The table tblLogs contains an ID (PK), a referenceID (FK) to an entry in tblFiles and an actionCode (either 0, 1 or 2).

Entries in tblFiles could look like:

```
1 | c:\root\files | test1.txt
2 | c:\root\files | test2.txt
3 | c:\root\files | test3.txt
```

Entries in tblFiles could look like

```
1 | 1 | 0
2 | 1 | 1
3 | 2 | 0
4 | 3 | 2
```

I need to get the path and the file name (from tblFiles) for all files that have only actionCode 0 in tblLogs. With the example above, the query should return:

```
c:\root\files | test2.txt
```

If this problem seems strange to you, it is because this is part of my assignment. Right now, I am trying to figure how to get entries with only actionCode 0 (ie only get a query that would return me referenceID 2). I have tryed different queries like:

```
SELECT referenceID FROM tblLogs WHERE actionCode = 0 AND (actionCode != 1 OR actionCode != 2);
```

I don't even know if a query like this is even possible though... If you guys could help me, I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: if this is the condition: `actionCode = 0` no need at all for this: `AND (actionCode != 1 OR actionCode != 2);`

Comment: @Jorge Campos True. I understand more conditions now after some researches. I was trying to find a way to "remove" the values that might have actionCode 1 or 2 from my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `max` and `min`:

```
select f.loc, f.name
from tblFiles f
  join tblLogs l on f.id = l.referenceid
group by f.loc, f.name
having max(l.actioncode) = 0 and min(l.actioncode) = 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6afa6/1)

Comment: This works great. I would never have guessed we could use min and max that way! For my own curiosity,  what would you have done if actionCode would have been a single character? or a VARCHAR?